# Run script on Fedora screen lock

Tags: locking, fedora, dbus, x11, gnome-3

I'm looking for a way to run a program when locking the screen in `Fedora 15` (linux). Basically I want to start running a motion detection program when the screen locks, or I manually hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, but I don't know what commands are being run or where to alias my own intermediate step in. I assume it's:

```
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

but am not sure how to go about this. Anybody know how, or a direction to start looking in?

**Edit**, since link was in a comment:
This is done with `dbus-monitor` and described [here](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F_Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F).

Comment: I retagged this in hopes that someone more familiar with the Gnome 3 screensaver might happen by and give you a more directly useful answer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dbus` system advertises screen locking; monitor for `ActiveChanged` on `org.gnome.ScreenSaver`. (see http://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html )

e.g. (word-wrapped for clarity)

```
    signal sender=:1.68 -> dest=(null destination) 
           serial=53 path=/org/gnome/ScreenSaver; 
           interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver; member=ActiveChanged
        boolean true
```

Unfortunately, this will require writing more code than just a shell script, I'm afraid; although I'd be curious if you could ask `dbus` to call your program as a handler for that signal, somehow; otherwise, I suppose you'd just start a daemon process and listen for that signal to be broadcast…

Comment: Your solution is a lot nicer than me wiping out a program link with an alias, and the ActiveChanged member does fire on locking, but I'm not sure how to add a handler to dbus. I'll look into this though, thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, anyway … `gnome-screensaver-command` just fires off a `dbus` signal, itself, I believe.

Comment: I dug through the dbus interface and turns out they changed a lot between whats documented and gnome 3, but they provide a nice, easy perl script here: http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F_Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F

Comment: correct link to @vityav comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F_Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F